# How do I use different ResultSet methods based on generic type from class in Java

Tags: java, generics, resultset

I have an sqlite database with a table 'parts' that contains the column 'part'.
This 'part' can be one of two things:

- String
- byte[] representing the bytes of an image

At one point in my java-program I need to fetch multiple 'parts' from the database and put them in a list. This is how I did it:

```java
    private ArrayList<String> getTextPart(String id) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT part FROM parts WHERE question_id = " + id + " ORDER BY part_id";
        ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                parts.add(rs.getString("part"));
            }
            return parts;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<byte[]> getImagePart(String id) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT part FROM parts WHERE question_id = " + id + " ORDER BY part_id";
        ArrayList<byte[]> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                parts.add(rs.getBytes("part"));
            }
            return parts;
        }
    }
```

Now the only difference between these two methods is the making of the ArrayList:

```java
ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<byte[]> parts = new ArrayList<>();
```

and the method called on the resultset:

```java
parts.add(rs.getString("part"));
parts.add(rs.getBytes("part"));
```

I thinks this is needless code duplication, but i can't seem to find a way to fix it.
I have tried to make a generic 'partFetcher' class, like so:

```java
public class PartFetcher<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> getPart(String id, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT part FROM parts WHERE question_id = " + id + " ORDER BY part_id";
        ArrayList<T> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                parts.add(rs.???);
            }
            return parts;
        }
    }

}
```

But I have no idea what to to call from the ResultSet when adding to the list.

So my question is:

How can a make PartFetcher<String> call `resultSet.getString("part")`
and PartFetcher<byte[]> `resultSet.getBytes("part")`
or is there a known pattern to solve these kinds of problems?

(sidenote: I have no control over how the database looks, so splitting the parts into TextParts and ImageParts is not possible)

Comment: You don't need to. Just use `ResultSet.getObject()`. It will return the correct type.

Comment: @user207421 how would I implement this? ```rs.getObject("part", T)``` doesn't seem to work. Documentation says the type of the second parameter is ```Class<T>```. Do i need to call T.class? thanks

Comment: There are other overloads of `getObject()` that don't require a `Class<T>`. Strange you didn't find them when you looked.

Comment: @user207421 are you talking about the ```ResultSet.getObject(String columnName)```?
I would need to cast to T when using this method, and that is something i would like to avoid.